# Dynamic memory addressing and deallocation

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to solve a problem for a web tutorial (non-marked) where I'm implementing a dynamic array. However, it fails in two places:

1. Where I try to delete a dynamic array in function `ResizeDynamicArray(...)`
2. It is outputting incorrect data. I expect to see:

   ```
   10 20 30 40 50
   10 30 40 50
   10 30 50
   ```

   ...but I get this instead:

   ```
   8723216 8716480 701955994 201375930 10 
   8723216 701955994 201375930 10 
   8723216 701955994 10
   ```

Requirements of the solution are:

- Use *pointer to pointer* instead of *reference to pointer* (btw I have successfully implemented a *reference to pointer* solution, but I am trying to figure out the *pointer to pointer* solution)
- No use of `malloc`/`free`
- No use of `vector`s
- Must use the declarations as shown

Could someone please suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
int* CreateDynamicArray(int capacity, int &size);
void DeleteDynamicArray(int* dynamicArray, int &size);
void InsertElement(int* dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity);
void DeleteElement(int* dynamicArray, int elementIndex, int &size);
void ResizeDynamicArray(int** dynamicArray, int newCapacity);
void PrintArray(int *ptrArray, int capacity);

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int capacity = 0;

    int* ptrArray = CreateDynamicArray(capacity, size);

    InsertElement(ptrArray, 10, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(ptrArray, 20, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(ptrArray, 30, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(ptrArray, 40, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(ptrArray, 50, size, capacity);
    PrintArray(ptrArray, size);

    DeleteElement(ptrArray, 1, size);
    PrintArray(ptrArray, size);
    DeleteElement(ptrArray, 2, size);
    PrintArray(ptrArray, size);

    DeleteDynamicArray(ptrArray, size);

    ptrArray = nullptr;

    return 0;
}


int* CreateDynamicArray(int capacity, int &size)
{
    size = 0;
    return new int[capacity];
}


void DeleteDynamicArray(int* dynamicArray, int &size)
{
    if (dynamicArray != nullptr) {
        delete[] dynamicArray;
        dynamicArray = nullptr;
    }
    size = 0;
}


void InsertElement(int* dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity)
{
    if (size > capacity)
        capacity += 2;
    else
        capacity += 1;
    ResizeDynamicArray(&dynamicArray, capacity);
    dynamicArray[size] = element;
    size++;
}


void DeleteElement(int* dynamicArray, int elementIndex, int &size)
{
    for(int i = elementIndex + 1; i < size; i++)
        dynamicArray[i - 1] = dynamicArray[i];
    size--;
}


void ResizeDynamicArray(int** dynamicArray, int newCapacity)
{
    int *newArray = new int[newCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < newCapacity; i++) {
        newArray[i] = (*dynamicArray)[i];
    }
//  if (*dynamicArray != nullptr) {
//      delete [] *dynamicArray;
//  }
    *dynamicArray = newArray;
}


void PrintArray(int *dynamicArray, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << dynamicArray[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have the solution, thanks to R Sahu.

```
int* CreateDynamicArray(int capacity, int &size);
void DeleteDynamicArray(int* dynamicArray, int &size);
void InsertElement(int** dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity);
void DeleteElement(int** dynamicArray, int elementIndex, int &size);
void ResizeDynamicArray(int** dynamicArray, int newCapacity);
void PrintArray(int *ptrArray, int capacity);

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int capacity = 0;

    int* ptrArray = CreateDynamicArray(capacity, size);

    InsertElement(&ptrArray, 10, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(&ptrArray, 20, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(&ptrArray, 30, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(&ptrArray, 40, size, capacity);
    InsertElement(&ptrArray, 50, size, capacity);
    PrintArray(ptrArray, size);

    DeleteElement(&ptrArray, 1, size);
    PrintArray(ptrArray, size);
    DeleteElement(&ptrArray, 2, size);
    PrintArray(ptrArray, size);

    DeleteDynamicArray(ptrArray, size);

    ptrArray = nullptr;

    return 0;
}


int* CreateDynamicArray(int capacity, int &size)
{
    size = 0;
    return new int[capacity];
}


void DeleteDynamicArray(int* dynamicArray, int &size)
{
    if (dynamicArray != nullptr) {
        delete[] dynamicArray;
        dynamicArray = nullptr;
    }
    size = 0;
}


void InsertElement(int** dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity)
{
    if (size > capacity)
        capacity += 2;
    else
        capacity += 1;
    ResizeDynamicArray(dynamicArray, capacity);
    (*dynamicArray)[size] = element;
    size++;
}


void DeleteElement(int** dynamicArray, int elementIndex, int &size)
{
    for (int i = elementIndex + 1; i < size; i++)
        (*dynamicArray)[i - 1] = (*dynamicArray)[i];
    size--;
}


void ResizeDynamicArray(int** dynamicArray, int newCapacity)
{
    int *newArray = new int[newCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < newCapacity; i++) {
        newArray[i] = (*dynamicArray)[i];
    }
    if (*dynamicArray != nullptr)
        delete[] * dynamicArray;
    *dynamicArray = newArray;
}


void PrintArray(int *dynamicArray, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << dynamicArray[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the problem in `InsertElement`. You have:

```
void InsertElement(int* dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity)
{
    ...
    ResizeDynamicArray(&dynamicArray, capacity);
    ...
}
```

In this function, you modify what `dynamicArray` points locally in the function. That does not change what the pointer points to in the calling function. As a consequence, you have the following problems.

1. The variable in the calling function does not point to the newly allocated memory you expected it to have.
2. The calling function uses memory it doesn't have, causing undefined behavior.
3. You have a memory leak. The memory acquired in the function is lost to the program as soon as you return from `InsertElement`.

The way to fix it would be to pass the pointer by reference.

```
void InsertElement(int*& dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity)
{
    ...
    ResizeDynamicArray(&dynamicArray, capacity);
    ...
}
```

I would recommend changing `ResizeDynamicArray` to also accept a pointer by reference. Using a `int**` is C-style, not C++ style. If you did change that, you can use

```
    ResizeDynamicArray(dynamicArray, capacity);
```

above.

Here's my suggestion for the function declarations. I take it that you can update the implementations accordingly.

```
int* CreateDynamicArray(int capacity, int &size);
void DeleteDynamicArray(int*& dynamicArray, int &size);
void InsertElement(int*& dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity);
void DeleteElement(int* dynamicArray, int elementIndex, int &size);
void ResizeDynamicArray(int*& dynamicArray, int newCapacity);
void PrintArray(int *ptrArray, int capacity);
```

---

I noticed that you have a bug in `ResizeDynamicArray`. You are using:

```
int *newArray = new int[newCapacity];
for(int i = 0; i < newCapacity; i++) {
    newArray[i] = (*dynamicArray)[i];
}
```

to copy values from the old array to the new array. However, the old array does not have as many elements as the new array. You end up copying values from memory that you are not supposed to access. It will be necessary to pass the old capacity to the function as an argument so you can copy the old values correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that R Sahu. I should have pointed out that a requirement of the exercise is to use a double pointer. I have succesfully used the reference to a pointer in the ResizeDynamicArray function without having to change the others.

Comment: @Tashycat, that's unfortunate. It's not the C++ way but you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: I must admit I'm a bit puzzled as to why the double pointer method is required. However, I'm more then happy to learn how to do things with double pointers. It is an exercise after all :-)

Comment: @Tashycat, If you must use `int**`, change all the places I suggested to use `int*&` by `int**`, and update the implementations and usages accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, R Sahu. I'm trying to atm but not getting it to run without crashing. I'll keep working at it.

Comment: I just changed the line
`void InsertElement(int** dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int &capacity);` (change to level 2 pointer)
Then fix the error lines like `InsertElement(&ptrArray, 10, size, capacity);` (pass address of main pointer to the function) and it worked as expected.

I just recommend that your `DeleteDynamicArray` should pass level 2 pointer too, because when you `delete` and assign to `nullptr`, it just the pointer in that function point to null, not the main one.

In short, to modify the "size" of level 1 pointer, you should use the level 2 one

Comment: Thank, Loi Ly :-)